# pandas convert dataframe to pivot_table where index is the sorting values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i have the following dataframe:

```
   site   height_id  height_meters
0  9      c3         24
1  9      c2         30
2  9      c1         36
3  3      c0         18
4  3      bf         24
5  3      be         30
6  4      10         18
7  4      0f         24
8  4      0e         30
```

i want to transform it to the following this column indexes is values of 'site' and the values is 'height_meters' and i want it to be indexed by the order of the values (i looked in the internet and didnt find somthing similar... tried to groupby and make some pivot table without success):

```
   9   3   4
0  24  18  18
1  30  24  24
2  36  30  24
```

the gap between numbers isn't necessary ...
here is the df

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    site=[9, 9, 9, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    height_id='c3,c2,c1,c0,bf,be,10,0f,0e'.split(','),
    height_meters=[24, 30, 36, 18, 24, 30, 18, 24, 30]
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter of column `site`:

```
print (my_df.groupby('site').cumcount())

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    1
8    2
dtype: int64
```

You can convert it to `index` with `site` column and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = my_df.set_index([my_df.groupby('site').cumcount(), 'site'])['height_meters'].unstack()
print (df)
site   3   4   9
0     18  18  24
1     24  24  30
2     30  30  36
```

Similar solution with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and column created by `cumcount`:

```
df = my_df.assign(new=my_df.groupby('site').cumcount()).pivot('new','site','height_meters')
print (df)
site   3   4   9
new             
0     18  18  24
1     24  24  30
2     30  30  36
```

If order is important add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by unique values of column `site`:

```
df = (my_df.set_index([my_df.groupby('site').cumcount(), 'site'])['height_meters']
           .unstack()
           .reindex(my_df['site'].unique(), axis=1))
print (df)
site   9   3   4
0     24  18  18
1     30  24  24
2     36  30  30
```

Last for remove `site` (`new`) columns and index names is possible use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
    3   4   9
0  18  18  24
1  24  24  30
2  30  30  36
```

Comment: love you man!!! thanks, can you add a little explaination avout the cumcount and unstack?

Comment: @ombk - not me, pandas ;)

Comment: man I really appreciate you, thank you very much, you make the world a lot better! (for those who doesnt know why i am so wmotional its because i use @jezreal answers over stackoverflow community!)